# SwiftUI TextField suggest OTP code without textContentType

Tags: textfield, ios13, one-time-password, swiftui

I have a strange behavior in my SwiftUI project when using the TextField view.

With the following code, the TextField *textContentType* is set to `nil` (or `.none`, or `UITextContentType.init(rawValue: "")`) but the keyboard suggest me an OTP code (if received recently, for example in the previous view). Why ?

I've try other valid *textContentType* like `.name`, `.address`, ... with no success (only textContentType `.password` and `.newPassword` disable the OTP suggestion).

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .textContentType(nil) // or .none, or UITextContentType.init(rawValue: "")
    }
}
```

With a UIKit project, UITextField works as expected (no keyboard suggestion). Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a carryover bug from UIKit.
Same problem there.

thanks for the tip with .password

sadly that bring on suggestion to fill in passwords